# Push existing Angular 7 Project to GitHub/GItlab?

Tags: angular, git, github, gitlab

Hey there I was trying to push an existing project (well, not really existing because I just created it from CLI) but the thing is, the angular folder gets locked up or the files inside it gets deleted somehow after pushing it to the my  repository.

here's a photo 
[image]

Look carefully at the icon of the folder.

now I cloned the project to another laptop but I can't open the folder of angular anymore

here's a photo

[image]

or do you have any suggestion how to push it

Answer (score 0):

1. create empty git repository
2. clone it
3. copy paste existing code there
   4.push and commit changes

Answer (score 0):

If it is the node_modules folder that is missing, then do the following. Anyone who wants to access the repository or if there is any collaborator, they can clone it and open the project. And then they'll have to run the following command

```
npm install
```

I had the same issue and this solved it

Comment: the folder is empty?

Comment: I think you have not added the files to your local repository. Try this. Go to your project folder using cmd and run this command "git add .". Then commit it and try pushing. Hope you are familiar with github commands

Comment: I did that. I think its about that sub module thingy

Comment: Don't you have any file inside the folder in the git repository

Comment: it contains files a whole angular project